# Negating an integer which sql query returned

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a SQL sub query,

```
SELECT `generateoffset` FROM `opa`.`sddrecurrencetype` WHERE `sddrecurrencetypeid`=1;
```

it returns as a result  `6`

What I am wondering is that, if its possible to get negative of what the value is returned from the query.

I tried to do it like this,

```
-(SELECT `generateoffset` FROM `opa`.`sddrecurrencetype` WHERE `sddrecurrencetypeid`=1)
```

I thought may be it will give me negative of what the result of the query would be like `-6`, but alas its not working like this.

Can some one please tell me , if its possible what I am trying to do.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: SELECT - `generateoffset` FROM `opa`.`sddrecurrencetype` WHERE `sddrecurrencetypeid`=1; `-` before the column, not before the `select`.

Comment: Thank you @vkp, indeed it worked!!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply the column result rather than the entire query:

```
SELECT `generateoffset` * -1 as 'generateoffset' 
FROM `opa`.`sddrecurrencetype` 
WHERE `sddrecurrencetypeid`=1;
```

Comment: Why not simply an unary `-`, i.e. `SELECT -generateoffset ...`?

Comment: @jarlh, that also works, I am not sure which one is better from performance perspective.....

Comment: Probably no measurable difference.

Comment: Personally, I don't negate things too often in queries - for me I like how obvious this is when you glance at it.  I would hope the performance is similar.